# Query with Totals Query results as criteria returns the expected number of results squared

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2010

**Background**

I am building an Access 2010 database that has a table [ControllerAdjustments] that keeps track of all adjustments made to controllers with an [AdjustmentID] autonumber field, a [ControllerID] field, an [AdjustmentDate] field, [Setpoint] field, and a [Power] field.  The [Power] field represents the power level when the adjustment was made.  Ultimately I need two queries to return two sets of results, one query should return the current status of all controllers (basically the most recent adjustment made on each controller) and the other should return the most recent adjustment made on each controller where power level is 100%.  I plan to use each of these queries to feed a report.  Note: field names changed slightly for convenience when typing, full names given in the code blocks...

**Method**

I focused on the Current Query first, and figured I would just copy it and make necessary changes to create a  100% Query.  I started with a totals query on the [ControllerAdjustments] table, that had [ControllerID] as a Group By field and [AdjustmentDate] as a field that returned the Max value.  This query returns exactly the number of records I expected, and after reviewing the sample bogus data I put in the table to check it, it seems to return exactly the records I need.  I then created a Select Query that returned all the fields I want in my Current Report, namely the [ControllerAdjustments] table and the related records in upstream related tables.  I then set the criteria for the [ControllerID] field in my Select Query to equal [Total_CurrentContAdjs]![ControllerID] and the [AdjustmentDate] in the Select Query to [Total_CurrentContAdjs]![MaxOfAdjustmentDate].  Running this query returns exactly what I want.  The SQL for this query is below:

```
SELECT List_Units.UnitID, List_EDTanks.TankNameShort, List_Controllers.ControllerType, ControllerAdjustments.AdjustmentDate, ControllerAdjustments.ControllerSetpoint, ControllerAdjustments.RxPower
FROM Total_ContAdjsCurrent, ((List_Units INNER JOIN List_EDTanks ON List_Units.UnitID = List_EDTanks.UnitID) INNER JOIN List_Controllers ON List_EDTanks.EDTankID = List_Controllers.EDTankID) INNER JOIN ControllerAdjustments ON List_Controllers.ControllerID = ControllerAdjustments.ControllerID
WHERE (((ControllerAdjustments.AdjustmentDate)=[Total_ContAdjsCurrent]![MaxOfAdjustmentDate]) AND ((ControllerAdjustments.ControllerID)=[Total_ContAdjsCurrent]![ControllerID]))
ORDER BY List_Units.Unit, List_EDTanks.TankSortOrder, List_Controllers.ControllerType DESC;
```

I then copied the Totals query and added a column for Power, selected Where, unchecked show, and put in 100 for criteria.  This works as expected.  I then copied my select query, and changed the criteria fields to direct to my new 100% Totals query.  This is where my problems begin.

**Problem**

The second 100% Query does not seem to like the criteria, as it initially throws out the familiar parameter window.  This is the SQL Statement for the second query, virtually the same except for referring to the 100% Totals query:

```
SELECT List_Units.UnitID, List_EDTanks.TankNameShort, List_Controllers.ControllerType, ControllerAdjustments.AdjustmentDate, ControllerAdjustments.ControllerSetpoint, ControllerAdjustments.RxPower
FROM Total_ContAdjsCurrent, Total_ContAdjsStdyState, ((List_Units INNER JOIN List_EDTanks ON List_Units.UnitID = List_EDTanks.UnitID) INNER JOIN List_Controllers ON List_EDTanks.EDTankID = List_Controllers.EDTankID) INNER JOIN ControllerAdjustments ON List_Controllers.ControllerID = ControllerAdjustments.ControllerID
WHERE (((ControllerAdjustments.AdjustmentDate)=[Total_ContAdjsStdyState]![MaxOfAdjustmentDate]) AND ((ControllerAdjustments.ControllerID)=[Total_ContAdjsStdyState]![ControllerID]))
ORDER BY List_Units.Unit, List_EDTanks.TankSortOrder, List_Controllers.ControllerType DESC;
```

Initially, Access did not add my Totals query into the show table box in design view, because its results were not directly used in the Select Query.  So, I added the Totals query to the top, and that allowed my query to run without asking for parameters, but now it returns the number of results I was expecting squared.  Basically if I am expecting 3 records: 1, 2, and 3, it is giving me: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, and 3.  For the life of me I cannot figure out why it is doing this, especially because the exact same setup for my Current Query returns exactly what is expected...  I thought maybe the where clause in my totals query had something to do with it, so I created a Select Query for the [ControllerAdjustments] table that returned all records with 100 for power.  I then used this query for my totals query instead of the totals query itself, but this did not do anything different.  I am at a loss, and not sure what else I can do to get the results I want.  Any suggestions welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply starting over from scratch and rebuilding my 100% query.  Reviewing the SQL statements, they look identical, however for some reason my query now returns the right number of records.  I have no idea why this worked, and am still curious what went wrong in the first place if anyone with time available cares to dig into it, but the original problem statement has been corrected--even if I have no idea how I did it haha...